# MYSQL restrict user access to information_schema

Tags: php, mysql

I have a MySQL server (Server version: 5.1.68-community; MySQL client version: 5.0.51a).  Is there any way to restrict ALL access to information_schema for all users?

What happens is that, some customer sites are getting hacked frequently through SQL Injection and they can get the database structure from information_schema table/view.  Of course, we need to change the PHP codes to prevent SQL Injection, but still I would like to restrict access to information_schema server-wide.

Please guide me... thanks in advance

Answer (score 33, accepted):

The [`INFORMATION_SCHEMA`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/information-schema.html) is a virtual database that holds meta-information about all databases accessible to current user. I.e. it's build dynamically according to user's permissions. It isn't real database. You should **not** try to change permissions to it in any case - it's updated dynamically according to server's state.

So your question has little sense. If someone will compromise some of users and get system control with it's permissions, he will be able to access to `INFORMATION_SCHEMA` for that user by definition (as that user can access any thing which is allowed by it's permissions - `INFORMATION_SCHEMA` is "a projection" of user's permissions).

Comment: thank you very much for your quick response.  My issue is not about someone compromising other user.  But with SQL Injection, anybody can inject an sql statement like `....%20union%20select%201,group_concat(table_name),3%20%20from%20information_schema.tables%20where%20table_schema=database()` (taken from an actual injection happened to my site) to PHP code and get the structure of the current database. I totally understand that vulnerability in the PHP code has to be fixed, but if we could restrict the SELECT privilege (at least) for all users from information_schema, will be safer.

Comment: You should realize: if SQL injection _was successful_ - then there's no way to prevent user from using it's own permissions. `INFORMATION_SCHEMA` is just a projection. If user has access to some table(s) - then he'll do that even without accessing that database. In your case, he'll just use `SHOW TABLES`

Comment: You are absolutely right and I totally agree with you... Regarding the sample Injection, with this they can get the table list and then go for another injection to get data, and then to add/edit/delete on these tables, we will be running into trouble.

Answer (score -4):

One cannot prevent access to the information_schema (yet), 
but in the case of sql-injections through GET Request, it is easy to do a:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}   !handle_error\.php
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING}   information_schema
RewriteRule  ^(.*?)          /handle_error.php [R=301,L]
```

in your **.htaccess** and this should save one some headache.

Comment: Then if I don't want a link to be opened, I'll just add "information_schema" to it. Example: I use "information_schema" as my nickname in your website, and any link with my nickname in it will be blocked. Same goes if I put. Plus, it gives no protection against POST

Comment: that's the choice of the website developer, your use case is probably never encountered, it's not necessary that pages will be displayed with the nickname in the querystring.
Otherwise you're fully right, cannot disagree.